# Rails Nested association lead to a nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these three model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :garden
end

class Garden < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_one   :garden_customer
  validates_uniqueness_of :idjardin, :message => "Este codigo jardin ya esta utilizado"
end

class GardenCustomer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :garden
end
```

If I run `project=Project.find(1)` and then `garden=project.garden.find(1)` everything is ok. But when i try to get the garden customers I got a nil object instead of an empty array or values, that is:

```
garden.garden_customer
```

is nil.

I can't call any method on garden.garden_customer.

Example of code:

```
@project=Project.find(params[:project_id])
@garden = @project.garden.find(params[:garden_id])
@garden_customers = @garden.garden_customer.all
```

I got the error "undefined method `all' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Show the code where you are creating the garden_customer

Comment: @Anand Code added to the question

Comment: try this maybe? garden belongs_to garden customer

Answer (score 0):

Since `Garden`is a has_many, it should really be setup like `has_many :gardens`

Edit: Also `garden_customer` is setup as a `has_one`relationships, so there is only 1 `garden_customer` per `garden` and so `garden.garden_customer.all` is wrong. `garden.garden_customer` itself would directly give you the associated `garden_customer` provided it was setup during creation.

Comment: it's a an has_one relationship

Comment: has_one is garden_customer, I am talking about garden in project

Comment: ok but this does not solve the problem I can't invoke new and all on garden_customer

Comment: updated my answer explaining why `all` on garden_customer doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks I got it for what concerning all. But if I want to create a new object? why I can't use new method?

Comment: You can do `garden.build_garden_customer`, refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference for more details

Comment: Thanks I used \@garden_customers = @garden.create_garden_customer but the garden_customer created does not contain the id of the relative garden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65323/discussion-between-dhruva-sagar-and-kerby82).